# Isolated system and conservation of momentum

Tags: momentum

I have a problem to understand isolated systems..If I have a ball and throw it upwards..then the momentum is not constant because the system is not isolated...and the reason is the external force from the earth (weight)...But if I see earth-ball as a system then I have an isolated system and as the ball moves upward the earth moves downwards..(Thing that we can't understand) because of inertia......THE PROBLEM IS THIS....Ican explain the movement of a boat from the air because of the external force from the air.....but what if I think boat-air as one system that is isolated....then the force from the air is internal...what is happening here with the conservation of momentum???

Comment: Please remove the screaming (all capital letters) from your post.

Comment: Also consider removing the ellipses.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's 3rd Law: "Action and Reaction" is the answer!

When the molecules of the air collide on the boat's sail, during the impact, forces of the same magnitude but with opposite direction are applied to the molecules and the sail, respectively. Since molecules are much lighter than the boat (whose sail is part of) they are bounced back. The change of the air molecules momentum, which is negative, is equal to the boat's change of momentum, which is positive and momentum is conserved!

Another way to understand this is to consider the classical problem of collision of two bodies and particular the case where one heavy body is stationary and one much lighter moves towards it, resulting in collision. After the collision the heavier body will start to move in the original direction of the lighter body while the lighter body will be bounced back. And all these are explained by momentum (and kinetic energy) conservation.

In your case (the one with the boat) of course you cannot see the "invisible" air bouncing back, but only a boat moving forward. Maybe this limit of our visual perception causes the confusion.

And about the sea, of course you can include it in the system but you don't need to do so in order to explain the phenomenon. It just adds a friction force to the boat which opposes the thrust of the air.

Comment: And what about a car that collides with a wall....if the system is earth-car-wall and is isolated....how can I explain what is happening with conservation of momentum....???....Can I say that "when the car stops,the earth moves to the opposite direction but because earth has big inertia we can't notice this?"...Thank you very much

Comment: Precisely! However, if the collision were elastic, you would see the car bouncing back. In the real world, the car will be smashed up and the collision will be inelastic. Momentum would still be conserved (the car's momentum would be transfered to the wall-earth) but the "lost energy" caused by the deformation of the car would make the car stop. Actually, there is not kinetic energy lost, but transformed to deformation energy

Comment: Please....I want to ask you a last question....The things that provide us wind power....The pylon (tower)..with the propeller....can I say that is isolated???.....The system pylon (tower) -propeller-wind can I think it as isolated???...And explain what is happening by the conservation of momentum....Like we explain the situation wind-Boat-sail???...There is not problem that is grounded;;;;....

Comment: Anything can be considered as isolated, also this. In this case, the shape of the wings will cause the air's molecules to bounce not in the same as their original direction, i.e. they will deflect. Take in mind that momentum is a conserved **vector** so if initially air's momentum was along the x-direction and after the impact with the wing has components both in the x and y axes, then the x-consevred component would push the earth back (via the wing-pylon) while the y-conserved component would push the wing in the y direction which would cause it to rotate.